# Multi search bar

Tags: html, css, search

This searches within three search engines.  I would like if you could tell me any ways to make this better:

```js
function google() {
  var good = document.getElementById("theStuff").value;
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + good;
}
function yahoo() {
  var good = document.getElementById("theStuff").value;
  window.location.href = 'http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=' + good;
}
function bing() {
  var good = document.getElementById("theStuff").value;
  window.location.href = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + good;
}
```

```css
.myButton {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 50px 19px 50px #ffffff;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 50px 19px 50px #ffffff;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 50px 19px 50px #ffffff;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #f6f6f6));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#ffffff;
 -moz-border-radius:6px;
 -webkit-border-radius:6px;
 border-radius:6px;
 border:3px solid #dcdcdc;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#666666;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:13px 45px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px -6px 0px #ffffff;
}
.myButton:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f6f6f6), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
.myButton {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 50px 19px 50px #ffffff;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 50px 19px 50px #ffffff;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 50px 19px 50px #ffffff;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #f6f6f6));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 5%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f6f6f6',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#ffffff;
 -moz-border-radius:6px;
 -webkit-border-radius:6px;
 border-radius:6px;
 border:3px solid #dcdcdc;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#666666;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:13px 45px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px -6px 0px #ffffff;
}
.myButton:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f6f6f6), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f6f6f6 5%, #ffffff 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="3" cols="50" id="theStuff"></textarea><br>
<a onclick="google()" target="blank" class="myButton">google</a><br>
<a onclick="yahoo()" class="myButton">yahoo</a><br>
<a onclick="bing()" class="myButton">bing</a><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider exporting the following line into a function:

```
var good = document.getElementById("theStuff");
```

This way, if you ever change the way the input is received, you'll only have to change it one place instead of three.

In terms of conventions:

- In HTML we don't use camel case, but instead we use dashes. So,
  `theStuff` should really be `the-stuff`, but that name doesn't really
  mean anything. Consider naming it `search-bar` or something.
- In your CSS, add a space before the value. `background:black` should look like `background: black` (space between `:` and `black`).